# dual boot win7 and ubuntu accidentally deleted ubuntu partition

Tags: boot

I had a dual boot Ubuntu Win7 combo, and I deleted the Ubuntu partition by mistake.

Now the system doesn't load.

I tried boot repair logged on: [Log-I](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11700429) and [Log-II](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11700500).

My system still doesn't boot. Can somebody help?

Comment: You can use windows repair DVD

Comment: I tried that. Win 7 dvd doesn't repair it